# How to log data to a file in Java

Tags: java, class, logging

I want to log some data in a log file. How to do it in such situation? I am attaching the code below.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

 interface DataprocessorInterface
 {
    void processdata(HTTPrequest data);

 }

class Dataprocessor implements DataprocessorInterface{

    void processdata(HTTPrequest data)
    {

      /*here i want to log HTTPrequest data by calling it in main,
       HTTPrequest is a class made by me .*/


    }
}
```